# Counting values from td's in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a problem with jQuery script. I'm trying to make a simple counting loop, for each tr. I got a table like below, and I want to select the second td, multiply it by two and add to the third td and display the result in the fourth td.

https://codepen.io/adeowsky/pen/YEgVKG

I'm trying to make it with the for each loop like below ->

```
<script>
(function($) {
    $('.sp-league-table tbody tr').each( function() {
        var pct = this.find('.data-pct').text();
        console.log(pct);
        //var pct = $('').hasClass('data-pct').text();
        //console.log(pct);
        var winy = $('.data-w').text();
        var losy = $('.data-l').text();

        /*var pkt = (winy*2) + (losy*2);
        $('.data-pct').text(pkt);*/
    });
})( jQuery );
</script>
```

But it doesn't work for me, where is the reason?

Comment: Where is `.sp-league-table`? Not on your html.

Comment: Because you are selecting all the elements, not the ones in the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems

- Your table does not have the required class
- you're not targeting the specific row's cells
- You should explicitly parse the string values to integers
- you've commented out the bit that does the calculation:

---

```
$(function(){

 $('.sp-league-table tbody tr').each( function() {
   var pct = $('.data-pct',this).text();

   var winy = parseInt($('.data-w',this).text(),10);
   var losy =parseInt($('.data-l',this).text(),10);

   var pkt = (winy*2) + (losy*2);
   $('.data-pct',this).text(pkt);
 });
})
```

Updated: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NwJjaO

Live example:

```js
$(function(){
  
 $('.sp-league-table tbody tr').each( function() {
   var pct = $('.data-pct',this).text();
   
   var winy = parseInt($('.data-w',this).text(),10);
   var losy =parseInt($('.data-l',this).text(),10);

   var pkt = (winy*2) + (losy*2);
   $('.data-pct',this).text(pkt);
 });
})
```

```css
table, tr, td, th {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="sp-league-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>W</th>
      <th>L</th>
      <th>PCT</th>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Name 1</td>
    <td class="data-w">12</td>
    <td class="data-l">0</td>
    <td class="data-pct">x</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name 2</td>
    <td class="data-w">9</td>
    <td class="data-l">3</td>
    <td class="data-pct">x</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="sp-league-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>W</th>
      <th>L</th>
      <th>PCT</th>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Name 1</td>
    <td class="data-w">12</td>
    <td class="data-l">0</td>
    <td class="data-pct">24</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name 2</td>
    <td class="data-w">6</td>
    <td class="data-l">5</td>
    <td class="data-pct">17</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I missed the class when typing the table, because it was just example, and quoted code was there because i was inspecting what's happening.

Well, that worked, i couldn't get to specific row, that was the problem. Now seems clear to me, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting all the elements with the class, not the one in the current row.

```
var tr = $(this);
var pCell = tr.find(".data-pct")
var wCell = tr.find('.data-w')
var lCell = tr.find('.data-l')
```